# Measuring TTFB and TTLB with HTTP in C#

Tags: c#

I am looking for ways to measure the TTFB (Time to First Byte) and TTLB (Time to Last Byte) while making a http web request to a specific web page.

How can I do the measurement in C#.

I am writing a monitoring tool to measure the TTFB and TTLB for accessing a web page.

Answer (score 3):

The code answered so far will give you the TTLB, to get the TTFB, though not accurate by 100% you have to listen to the event `DownloadProgressChanged` of the `WebClient` class, and on its first call record the time recorded by the `StopWatch` so far, without stopping it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a blocking call with [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) and measure the time it takes:

```
     using (var wc = new WebClient())
     {
         var sw = new Stopwatch();
         sw.Start();
         wc.DownloadData("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
         sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time (ms): " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
     }
     Console.ReadLine();
```

Or if you need to do it async:

```
    static Stopwatch sw;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var wc = new WebClient()) {
            sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            wc.DownloadDataCompleted +=wc_DownloadDataCompleted;
            wc.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("http://www.stackoverflow.com"));

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void wc_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time (ms): " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

Of course, you would want to trap errors and check the http response to ensure that the request was successful but you get the idea.

Comment: Any reason you're doing date math rather than using the Stopwatch class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx