# How to get time to first byte with HttpClient class c#

Tags: c#, http, testing, httpclient, metrics

Here's the code I am currently using to make calls to the api, where `api` is a string passed into the function. Set up of the httpClient is done beforehand outside of the method.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(api);
String strResp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
```

Is there a way I can track metrics like time to first byte (TTFB) using this code, or will I have to go another route?

Comment: Do you mean you need to keep the `ReadAsStringAsync` code in there?

Comment: I mean to ask is it possible (and if so how), to get metrics like TTFB with my current code. If it isn't possible, then I ask for an alternate way to make the api calls so that I can track TTFB and the like.

Comment: Does it have to be TTFB, or is TTLB also enough?

Comment: Hmm. Do you get to control the construction of the `HttpClient`? If so, you could potentially create one with a custom `HttpMessageHandler` which might help...

Comment: I do control that construction. That class is new to me (as is the rest of this), I'll take a look and see if it can do what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using FiddlerCore by Telerik to get TTFB and loads of other useful metrics.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the `HttpClient.GetAsync(string requestUri, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)` method with `HttpCompleteOption.ResponseHeadersRead`. This should return the HttpResponseMessage as soon as the header is read (not exactly TTFB - "Time to first byte", but TTHR - "Time till header read")

Then you could measure this time using stopwached:

```
sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(api);
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("TTFB: " + sw.EleapsedMilliseconds)
String strResp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

But this is also very unreliable due to the parallel nature of this code.

[In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556573/measuring-ttfb-and-ttlb-with-http-in-c-sharp) someone advices to use `WebClient`and its `DownloadProgressChanged` in combination with a 'StopWatch'.

Comment: I'm pretty new to these requests. Could you explain the difference between TTHR and TTFB? Is it just that TTHR is the first byte plus the few other bytes included with the header?

Comment: TTFB is the time between _sending the request_ and _receiving the first response byte_ 

whereas

TTLB represents the time between _sending the request_ and _receiving the last response byte_.

The naming TTHR should have been more of a "joke" was just introduce by myself :P It means time between _sending the request_ till _receiving the complete header_.

Comment: cool, so the header is just the response status and all that other meta info, not the actual content returned by the api?

Comment: Yes. [Here is a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) of all possible fields in the header.